# Updating mongodb from a spreadsheet

Tags: json, mongodb

I have a Google Doc Spreadsheet

with

```
key        number
-----      ---------
abc        111
foo        222
...
```

I want to take this data from Google Docs, and update existing data within MongoDB.

Whats the best way to find(key: 'abc') and update with number: 111, foreach row within MongoDB ?

Seems like I need to somehow export this to JSON, then run some JS that will update each key with the new number.

Thanks

Comment: You will have to export the file from Google Docs, for example as CSV and go from there. If you really want to use MongoDB you'll have to import to MongoDB first. I'm not sure why you would want to do that tho.

Comment: Sorry, maybe it wasn't clear, I have data in MOngoDB already that I want to UPDATE with this data.

Comment: Export the data, parse it in a programming language of your choice that can interface with mongo and you should be good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Export the data from Google Docs to a CSV file.

```
gdocs.csv
```

Create a file describing the CSV file - one line per field in the CSV file. `gdocsFields.txt` could look like this:

```
key
number
```

Import the data into your mongo instance in a temporary collection, e.g. `temp`:

```
mongoimport --type csv -c temp --fieldFile gdocsFields.txt < gdocs.csv
```

Now update your live collection, e.g. `live` with a query from the mongo console. Have a look at this example that also creates the imported data for you for testing. It pastes directly in to the `mongo` console:

```
db.temp.drop();
db.live.drop();

db.temp.insert({key:'abc', number:111});
db.temp.insert({key:'foo', number:222});
db.temp.insert({key:'xxx', number:333});
db.temp.insert({key:'yyy', number:444});
db.temp.insert({key:'zzz', number:555});

db.live.insert({key:'abc', number:100});
db.live.insert({key:'foo', number:200});
db.live.insert({key:'xxx', number:300});
db.live.insert({key:'yyy', number:400});
db.live.insert({key:'zzz', number:500});

// Update every record
var keys = db.temp.find();
keys.forEach(function(doc){
    db.live.update(
        { key:doc.key },
        { $set: {number:doc.number} },
        { upsert: true }
    );
    print(doc.key);
});

// Print out the live collection
var keys = db.live.find();
keys.forEach(function(doc){
    print(doc.key + " is now: " + doc.number);
});
```

Not the most efficient way but it should be easy to follow the process.

Comment: Thanks this is what I was looking for. I knew there was a way to do it within the console.